# Problem faced when running loop on a column

Tags: python, loops, dataframe

I have a numerical dataset with few columns with numerical values.

I tried to run the below code:

```
df2["Status"] = 'MOVEMENT'

for i in range(len(df2)-1):
    if (df2.loc[i,'BUSP'] <= 0.06) & (df2.loc[i,'Digital Input-1 (Ignition Status)'] != 1):
        df2.loc[i, "Status"] == 'STOP'
    elif (df2.loc[i,'MAINTENANCEP'] <= 0.08) & (df2.loc[i,'Digital Input-1 (Ignition Status)'] != 1):
        df2.loc[i, "Status"] == 'MAINTENANCE'
```

But it throws the below error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

How can i solve this issue? Is there any other way to simplify the code?

Comment: add sample data and expected output in your question

Comment: why are you using `==` ?

Comment: even if i add single '=' it is throwing same error